# OnItemSelected в спинере вызывается не тогда когда надо

Tags: android, android-spinner

Всем доброго вечера! У меня есть два фрагмента, один вызывает другой и получает из него результат. В обоих фрагментах есть по одному одинаковому спинеру, которые берут свои данные из одного синглтона. При переходе из первого фрагмента во второй, я передаю id выбранного элемента из первого спинера, который во втором спокойно ставится. Но обратная ситуация не работает. Если во втором фрагменте я меняю значение спинера, то первый его таковым не ставит. Более того, из логов видно, что onItemSelected вызывается вообще не в тот момент, в который должен, либо я что-то сильно упускаю. Привожу код и логи, очень надеюсь на вашу помощь! 
Fragment1:

```
public class FragmentMainWindow extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
private static final int REQUEST_NEW_OPERATION = 0;
private static final String LOG_CODE = "LOG_CODE";

private SpendingLab mSpendingLab;

private PieGraph mPieGraph;
private LinearLayout mPieChartContainer;
private int mLastNumInDB = -1;
private String[][] mDataBase;

private Spinner mSpinnerAccount;
private int mCurrentAccountId = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mDataBase = new String[100][3];

    mSpendingLab = SpendingLab.getInstance(getActivity());

    mPieGraph = new PieGraph();
    Log.d(LOG_CODE, "FragmentMainWindow ### Opened main window fragment (onCreate now).");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_window, parent, false);
    Log.d(LOG_CODE, "FragmentMainWindow ### onCreateView");
    //Making spinner for account
    mSpinnerAccount = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner_account_main);
    setAccountSpinner(mCurrentAccountId, mSpendingLab.getAccountsNames());
    Log.d(LOG_CODE, "FragmentMainWindow ### currentAccountId is - " + Integer.toString(mCurrentAccountId));

    mSpinnerAccount.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.d(LOG_CODE, "FragmentMainWindow ### onItemSelected called");
            if (id == mSpendingLab.getAccountsNames().size() - 1){
                Log.d(LOG_CODE, "FragmentMainWindow ### User required creating new account dialog");
                AlertDialog.Builder builderDialogNewAccount = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                final EditText editTextNewAccount = new EditText(getActivity());
                builderDialogNewAccount.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.alert_dialog_new_account_title));
                builderDialogNewAccount.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.alert_dialog_new_account_message));
                builderDialogNewAccount.setView(editTextNewAccount);

                builderDialogNewAccount.setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.alert_dialog_button_create),
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                mSpendingLab.addAccountNameAtIndex(mSpendingLab.getAccountsNames().size() - 1, editTextNewAccount.getText().toString());
                                setAccountSpinner(mSpendingLab.getAccountsNames().size() - 2, mSpendingLab.getAccountsNames());
                                Log.d(LOG_CODE, "FragmentMainWindow ### User added new account");
                            }
                        });
                builderDialogNewAccount.setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.alert_dialog_button_cancel),
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                mSpinnerAccount.setSelection(mCurrentAccountId);
                                Log.d(LOG_CODE, "FragmentMainWindow ### User pressed cancel in new account dialog");
                            }
                        });
                builderDialogNewAccount.setCancelable(true);
                builderDialogNewAccount.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        mSpinnerAccount.setSelection(mCurrentAccountId);
                        Log.d(LOG_CODE, "FragmentMainWindow ### User canceled new account dialog by pressing back button");
                    }
                });

                builderDialogNewAccount.show();
            }
            else if (mLastNumInDB != -1){
                Log.d(LOG_CODE, "FragmentMainWindow ### User changed account on " + mSpinnerAccount.getSelectedItem() + ". currentAccountId is - " + Integer.toString(mCurrentAccountId) + ". Id in onItemSelected is - " + Long.toString(id));
                createNewPieGraph();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            //nothing to do
        }
    });

    mPieChartContainer = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout_pieChart_container);
    if (mLastNumInDB == -1){
        //Initing empty PieGraph if we have no values
        GraphicalView graphicalView = mPieGraph.getEmptyGraphicalView(getActivity());
        mPieChartContainer.addView(graphicalView);
        Log.d(LOG_CODE, "FragmentMainWindow ### Empty pieGraph was made");
    }
    else{
        Log.d(LOG_CODE, "FragmentMainWindow ### createNewPieGraph method was called");
        createNewPieGraph();
    }

    //Click on minus button
    ImageButton operationButtonMinus = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.operation_button_minus);
    operationButtonMinus.setOnClickListener(this);



    return v;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view){
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.operation_button_minus:
            //Making Bundle with account and category for autofill in operation fragment
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("account", mSpinnerAccount.getSelectedItemPosition());

            FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentOperationWindow fragment = new FragmentOperationWindow();
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            fragment.setTargetFragment(FragmentMainWindow.this, REQUEST_NEW_OPERATION);
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_main_window_container, fragment, "operation fragment opened").addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) return;

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_NEW_OPERATION){
        String newSpending = (String) data.getSerializableExtra(FragmentOperationWindow.NEW_OPERATION_SPEND);
        int newSpendingAccountInt = (int) data.getSerializableExtra(FragmentOperationWindow.NEW_OPERATION_ACCOUNT);
        int newSpendingCategoryInt = (int) data.getSerializableExtra(FragmentOperationWindow.NEW_OPERATION_CATEGORY);
        mCurrentAccountId = newSpendingAccountInt;
        String newSpendingAccount = Integer.toString(newSpendingAccountInt);
        String newSpendingCategory = Integer.toString(newSpendingCategoryInt);

        mLastNumInDB++;
        mDataBase[mLastNumInDB][0] = newSpendingAccount;
        mDataBase[mLastNumInDB][1] = newSpendingCategory;
        mDataBase[mLastNumInDB][2] = newSpending;
        Log.d(LOG_CODE, "FragmentMainWindow ### Returned from operation fragment. Account: " + newSpendingAccount + ". Category: " + newSpendingCategory + ". Spending: " + newSpending);
    }
}

private void createNewPieGraph (){
    int currentAccountId = mSpinnerAccount.getSelectedItemPosition();
    Log.d(LOG_CODE, "FragmentMainWindow ### Current selected item in account spinner is - " + Integer.toString(currentAccountId));
    ArrayList<Integer> currentCategorysList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Double> currentSpendingsList = new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<String> currentCategorysNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> currentCategoryColorsList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    //currentSpendingsList - is for spendings,  currentCategorysList - is for category names,
    //currentCategorysNameList - is for category names, we'll use to create pieGraph
    //currentCategoryColorsList - is for colors, we'll do same as with currentCategorysNameList

    for (int i = 0; i <= mLastNumInDB; i++){
        if (Integer.valueOf(mDataBase[i][0]) == currentAccountId){
            if (!currentCategorysList.contains(mDataBase[i][1])){
                currentCategorysList.add(Integer.valueOf(mDataBase[i][1]));
                currentSpendingsList.add(Double.valueOf(mDataBase[i][2]));
            }
            else{
                int index = findValueInIntegerArrayList(Integer.valueOf(mDataBase[i][1]), currentCategorysList);
                if (index > -1){
                    double value = currentSpendingsList.get(index);
                    currentSpendingsList.set(index, value + Double.valueOf(mDataBase[i][2]));
                }
                else{
                    Log.d(LOG_CODE, "FragmentMainWindow ### findValueInIntegerArrayList did not find value");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    GraphicalView graphicalView;
    if (currentCategorysList.size() > 0){
        for (int i = 0; i < currentCategorysList.size(); i++){
            currentCategorysNameList.add(mSpendingLab.getCategory(currentCategorysList.get(i)));
            currentCategoryColorsList.add(mSpendingLab.getColor(currentCategorysList.get(i)));
        }
        graphicalView = mPieGraph.getGraphicalView(getActivity(), currentSpendingsList, currentCategorysNameList, currentCategoryColorsList);

    }
    else{
        graphicalView = mPieGraph.getEmptyGraphicalView(getActivity());
    }
    mPieChartContainer.removeAllViews();
    mPieChartContainer.addView(graphicalView);
}

private int findValueInIntegerArrayList(int value, ArrayList<Integer> arrayList){
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++){
        if (arrayList.get(i) == value){
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

private void setAccountSpinner(int indexOfCurrentItem, ArrayList<String> accountNames){
    String[] arrayAccountNames = accountNames.toArray(new String[accountNames.size()]);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterAccount = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.spinner_item_main_window, arrayAccountNames);
    adapterAccount.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mSpinnerAccount.setAdapter(adapterAccount);
    mSpinnerAccount.setSelection(indexOfCurrentItem);
    Log.d(LOG_CODE, "FragmentMainWindow ### SpinnerAccount set. Current Item: " + Integer.toString(indexOfCurrentItem) + ". Account names: " + accountNames);
}
}
```

Fragment2:

```
public class FragmentOperationWindow extends Fragment {
public static final String NEW_OPERATION_ACCOUNT = "com.example.dtar2.moneymanager.ACCOUNT";
public static final String NEW_OPERATION_SPEND = "com.example.dtar2.moneymanager.SPEND";
public static final String NEW_OPERATION_CATEGORY = "com.example.dtar2.moneymanager.CATEGORY";

private static final String LOG_CODE = "LOG_CODE";
private final int REQUEST_NEW_CATEGORY = 1;

private SpendingLab mSpendingLab;

private String spendind = "";

private Spinner mSpinnerAccount;
private Spinner mSpinnerCategory;
private int currentAccountId = 0;
private int currentCategoryId = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(LOG_CODE, "FragmentOperationWindow ### Opened operation fragment (onCreate now).");

    mSpendingLab = SpendingLab.getInstance(getActivity());
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_operation_window, parent, false);
    Log.d(LOG_CODE, "FragmentOperationWindow ### Operation fragment onCreateView");

    //Making spinner for account choosing
    mSpinnerAccount = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner_account);
    setAccountSpinner(getArguments().getInt("account"), mSpendingLab.getAccountsNames());
    mSpinnerAccount.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (id == mSpendingLab.getAccountsNames().size() - 1){
                Log.d(LOG_CODE, "FragmentOperationWindow ### User required creating new account dialog");
                AlertDialog.Builder builderDialogNewAccount = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                final EditText editTextNewAccount = new EditText(getActivity());
                builderDialogNewAccount.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.alert_dialog_new_account_title));
                builderDialogNewAccount.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.alert_dialog_new_account_message));
                builderDialogNewAccount.setView(editTextNewAccount);

                builderDialogNewAccount.setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.alert_dialog_button_create),
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                mSpendingLab.addAccountNameAtIndex(mSpendingLab.getAccountsNames().size() - 1, editTextNewAccount.getText().toString());
                                setAccountSpinner(mSpendingLab.getAccountsNames().size() - 2, mSpendingLab.getAccountsNames());
                                Log.d(LOG_CODE, "FragmentOperationWindow ### User added new account");
                            }
                        });
                builderDialogNewAccount.setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.alert_dialog_button_cancel),
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                mSpinnerAccount.setSelection(currentAccountId);
                                Log.d(LOG_CODE, "FragmentOperationWindow ### User pressed cancel in new account dialog");
                            }
                        });
                builderDialogNewAccount.setCancelable(true);
                builderDialogNewAccount.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        mSpinnerAccount.setSelection(currentAccountId);
                        Log.d(LOG_CODE, "FragmentOperationWindow ### User canceled new account dialog by pressing back button");
                    }
                });
                builderDialogNewAccount.show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            //nothing to do
        }
    });

    //Making spinner for category choosing
    mSpinnerCategory = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner_category);
    setCategorySpinner(currentCategoryId, mSpendingLab.getCategorysNames());
    mSpinnerCategory.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (id == mSpendingLab.getCategorysNames().size() - 1){
                Log.d(LOG_CODE, "FragmentOperationWindow ### User required creating new category dialog");

                FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentCreateNewCategory fragment = new FragmentCreateNewCategory();
                fragment.setTargetFragment(FragmentOperationWindow.this, REQUEST_NEW_CATEGORY);
                fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_main_window_container, fragment, "creating new category").addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            //nothing to do
        }
    });

    //Reading what user enterned in spending
    EditText editTextSpending = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText_spending);
    editTextSpending.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            //
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            //
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            spendind = s.toString();
        }
    });


    //Watching commit-button pressing
    Button buttonCommit = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button_commit);
    buttonCommit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
        }
    });

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d(LOG_CODE, "FragmentOperationWindow ### onActivityResult");
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) return;

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_NEW_CATEGORY){
        String newCategoryName = (String) data.getSerializableExtra(NEW_CATEGORY_NAME);
        int newCategoryColor = (int) data.getSerializableExtra(NEW_CATEGORY_COLOR);
        mSpendingLab.addCategoryNameAtIndex(mSpendingLab.getCategorysNames().size() - 1, newCategoryName);
        mSpendingLab.addColorId(newCategoryColor);
        currentCategoryId = mSpendingLab.getCategorysNames().size() - 2;
        setCategorySpinner(currentCategoryId, mSpendingLab.getCategorysNames());

    }
}

private void sendResult(int resultCode){
    if (getTargetFragment() == null){
        return;
    }

    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.putExtra(NEW_OPERATION_SPEND, spendind);
    i.putExtra(NEW_OPERATION_ACCOUNT, mSpinnerAccount.getSelectedItemPosition());
    i.putExtra(NEW_OPERATION_CATEGORY, mSpinnerCategory.getSelectedItemPosition());

    getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), resultCode, i);
    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
}

private void setAccountSpinner(int indexOfCurrentItem, ArrayList<String> accountNames){
    currentAccountId = indexOfCurrentItem;
    String[] arrayAccountNames = accountNames.toArray(new String[accountNames.size()]);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterAccount = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.spinner_item_main_window, arrayAccountNames);
    adapterAccount.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mSpinnerAccount.setAdapter(adapterAccount);
    mSpinnerAccount.setSelection(indexOfCurrentItem);
    Log.d(LOG_CODE, "FragmentOperationWindow ### SpinnerAccount set. Current Item: " + Integer.toString(indexOfCurrentItem) + ". Account names: " + accountNames);
}

private void setCategorySpinner(int indexOfCurrentItem, ArrayList<String> accountNames){
    String[] arrayCategoryNames = accountNames.toArray(new String[accountNames.size()]);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterCategory = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.spinner_item_operation_window, arrayCategoryNames);
    adapterCategory.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mSpinnerCategory.setAdapter(adapterCategory);
    mSpinnerCategory.setSelection(indexOfCurrentItem);
}
}
```

Логи (сразу с момента возвращения из второго фрагмента):

```
FragmentMainWindow ### Returned from operation fragment. Account: 1. Category: 4. Spending: 6                                                               
FragmentMainWindow ### onCreateView                                           
FragmentMainWindow ### SpinnerAccount set. Current Item: 1. Account names: [Card, Cash, New account]                                                     
FragmentMainWindow ### currentAccountId is - 1                                 
FragmentMainWindow ### createNewPieGraph method was called                    
FragmentMainWindow ### Current selected item in account spinner is - 1         
FragmentMainWindow ### onItemSelected called (тот момент где onItemSelected не должен вызываться)                                                             
FragmentMainWindow ### User changed account on Card. currentAccountId is - 1. Id in onItemSelected is - 0                                                         
FragmentMainWindow ### Current selected item in account spinner is - 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался сам и нашёл интересное ( по моему мнению) свойство Spinner'а, которое не совсем очевидно и может ввести в ступор новичков. При вызове setSelection вызывается метод onItemSelected, однако не из места вызова, а только после завершения метода onCreateView. То есть, если у вас несколько раз вызывается setselection в onCreateView, то лишь после его завершения будет вызван метод onItemselected столько раз, сколько ставился setSelection/